# Real time data validation or searching

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I would like to know is there any best way to create realtime data checker from page to backend like for example PHP to MySQl aside from sending an Ajax every 5 seconds using these lines of code.

```
  setInterval(function(){
      $.ajax({
          url: "url",
          type: "post",
          data: {sys_id: <some id>},
          success: function(returnedValue){
              `some dom manipulation here`;
          }
      })    
  },5000);
```

Note that this is just a sample ajax execution.

Comment: Why checking so many times? check only when something changes, or when submitted.

Comment: Hi, i just want to know the process of real time retrieval of data like for example is the notification toggle pof facebook

Comment: salam i think you need something like database notification, this post my help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32717824/notification-system-using-php-and-mysql

Comment: A server-sent-event might be best solution for this. Read here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp